# Sftp Connection Via Gigolo on Debian 10 "Buster"

Tags: debian, ssh, sftp

Trying here to establish `sftp` connection via `Gigolo` on Debian 10 "Buster" with Gigolo application, but when connecting at `sftp://user@192.168.41.72`, for example, receives here `Location is not mountable` error message.

Already installed `gvfs-fuse` package, created `fuse` group and added user in it, before trying to stablish `sftp` connection without success.

Any idea of how to connect it?

Comment: I don't know about Gigolo, but for a new group membership to be effective you might need to logout the user sessions.

Comment: If you connect yo the server using ssh Key that putted in different folder than default, you should add it to `~/.ssh/config` file like `Host 199.199.199.100 
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey/id_rsa`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just managed here on how to do it, as follows:

a) It's install `sshfs` package, via:

`$ sudo apt install sshfs`

b) Add username in `fuse` group, via:

`$ gpasswd -a username fuse`

c) If error message is displayed, create group before it:

`$ sudo groupadd fuse`

d) Then install `gvfs-backends` package:

`$ sudo apt install gvfs-backends`

e) Go in `Edit` tab, `Preferences` option, then enter preffered File Manager, which may be `thunar` that's installed by default.

f) Finally enter `ssh` server info and connect it.